# Find the Order of this Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the order of $U_N$ for $N=p_1*p_2*p_3$ such that $p_i$ is prime.  $U_N$ are all the integers relatively prime to $N$.
I believe that this is simply adding up each $p_i$ in this case. It works for 2,3, and 5, but if my memory serves me right this is a special group that I forget about. The next smallest set of 3 primes is 2,3, and 7. But that is quite a lot to do by brute force. Can somebody point me in the right direction if they have seen this anywhere else?

Comment: What is your definition of $U_N$?

Comment: edited. my apologizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|U(n)|=\phi(n)$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

For $n=p_1p_2p_3$ this gives $$\phi(n)=\phi(p_1p_2p_3)=\phi(p_1)\phi(p_2)\phi(p_3)=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)(p_3-1)$$

Assuming $p_i\neq p_j$ for $j\neq i$.

Comment: right. I was doing $U_{30}$ as 10 not 8. thanks